# how to delete 5th max salary from emp table and he should also be from dallas in dept table

Tags: sql

I am not getting the result l thought.
 I have tried using:

```
DELETE FROM emp c
WHERE SAL IN (
    SELECT SAL
    FROM EMP A
    WHERE DEPTNO IN (
        SELECT DEPTNO
        FROM DEPT
        WHERE LOC IN ('DALLAS')
    )
    AND 4 = (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM EMP B
        WHERE A.SAL< B.SAL
    )
);
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Quick point of clarification: the fifth-highest Dallas salary, or the fifth-highest salary (and if it's not from Dallas, then don't delete)?

Comment: If this worked it would be deleting salaries <= the fith highest salary, not just the 5th. What do you really want?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM emp c
WHERE SAL IN (
    SELECT TOP 1
        sub1.SAL
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP 5
            SAL
        FROM EMP A
        inner join DEPT ON a.DEPTNO=DEPT.DEPTNO and DEPT.LOC='DALLAS'
        ORDER BY SAL DESC
    ) sub1
    ORDER BY sub1.SAL ASC
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rank over Salary must help in detecting the 5th max salary:

```
DELETE FROM emp where sal in(
   select sal from(
         SELECT sal, RANK() OVER (order by sal DESC) myrank
            FROM emp)
    where myrank=5
)
   and  DEPTNO IN (
    SELECT DEPTNO
    FROM DEPT
    WHERE LOC IN ('DALLAS')
```

If you want the 5th salary to be within a department in Dallas, i.e. not across all the salaries, try something like this:

```
DELETE FROM emp where sal in(
   select sal from(
         SELECT sal, RANK() OVER (partition by depno order by sal DESC) myrank
            FROM emp)
    where myrank=5
)
   and  DEPTNO IN (
    SELECT DEPTNO
    FROM DEPT
    WHERE LOC IN ('DALLAS')
```